# MySQL foreign key cannot be created (index problems?)

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem making some foreign keys...
When I try to define the foreign key in MySQL Workbench, I get the following message:

> Selected column 'playerName' must be indexed and be of a compatible type for a Foreign Key to be created.

There my problem starts: I'm pretty sure, that the column (towns.playerName) **is** indexed and it's definitively of the same type ( VARCHAR(255) )...
[Indexes of 'towns'](http://www.youscreen.de/hgvoqqjk16.jpg)
I want to add a Foreign Key from `players.name (primary key, not null, unique)` to `towns.playersName(not null)`.
So what can I do to get the foreign key created?
It seems i am doing something wrong...

PS: I'm sorry, if there is already a question for this...

EDIT: I just tried again (exactly as I did before several times) and now it works... really strange
Perhaps a bug in MySQL Workbench??

Comment: `towns.playersName` must have an index on it too. newer mysql versions would create the necessary index automatically, but on older versions, you have to index the fields-used-in-foreign-key yourself.

Comment: `towns.playerName` **is** indexed... perhaps not totally clear; edited question

Comment: Try to create the foreign key the opposite way. The constraint/foreign key must be on the table not having the unique index. Check this post out for an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383182/mysql-table-with-a-varchar-column-as-foreign-key  Also, it could be useful if you post more sql.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem a number of times, but finally found a interesting and useful concept which I missed while learning mysql.
If a column is not a 'key' in the table 1, you cannot add it as foreign key unless it should have an index.
So I make the column a indexed column.

e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX any_name ON table1 (column1);
```

finally, I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the key you are trying to access through the foreign key needs to be a primary key in the other table.

Comment: Not required. Even Non-Primary keys can be referenced as Foreign Key but, they have to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error message. I checked the type of the column in both the tables. It was `int` in one table whereas `varchar` in the other table. It should be the same type in both. On using the same type in both the tables, it worked fine.