# Unable to create foreign key in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am trying to create a table with a varchar column as foreign key but MySQL gives me an error while creating the table. My query is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_hesco_subdivision` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`circle_code` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`circle_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`division_code` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`sub_div_code` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`division_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sub_div_code`),
KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The above table is already in used

```
Create table `accurate_mam`.`meter_ping`(  
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`meter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`meter_msn` varchar(100),
`sub_div_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`sub_div_name` varchar(100),
primary key (`id`),
constraint `FK_PING_METER_ID` foreign key (`meter_id`) references 
`accurate_mam`.`meters`(`id`) on delete Cascade,
constraint `FK_PIN_SUB_DIV` foreign key (`sub_div_code`) references 
`accurate_mam`.`survey_hesco_subdivision`(`sub_div_code`) on delete Cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB charset=latin1 collate=latin1_swedish_ci
```

The error I am getting is

> Error Number : 1005 
>   Error Message: Can't create table `accurate_mam`.`meter_ping` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I have already looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383182/mysql-table-with-a-varchar-column-as-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

So, just create a index like this, before creating child table :

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_survey_hesco_subdivision_sub_div_code` ON survey_hesco_subdivision(sub_div_code);
```

Although, It is not best practice to use non-unique column as reference columns in relationship. `DELETE CASCADE` will not behave properly in that case. I will suggest you create a unique key on `sub_div_code` of primary table as well.

For more details, refere to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Source : [Cannot add foreign key - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526055/mysql-cannot-create-foreign-key-constraint?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already run `CREATE TABLE meters`?  There error is caused by that table being missing.  Let's see that `CREATE`.